QLineEdit обрезает текст при фокусе, курсор ниже текста
При вводе текста в QLineEdit он обрезается сверху, словно его перекрывает каким-то другим полем, подозреваю что это какой-то скрытый border. И, как мне кажется, курсор располагается ниже текста из-за этой же проблемы. Когда убираю фокус QLineEdit текст выглядит нормально. Ну и вишенка на торте: проблема возникает только при запуске программы на Linux(Raspberry Pi), при работе на Windows проблемы нет.
Кусок кода из design.py (Qt Designer):
        self.edit_1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.page_edit)
        self.edit_1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 38))
        self.edit_1.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(80, 38))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("PF DinDisplay Pro")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.edit_1.setFont(font)
        self.edit_1.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.edit_1.setStyleSheet("\n"
"QLineEdit{\n"
"            outline: none;\n"
"            color: #c0c0c0;\n"
"            border: 2px solid #A38415;\n"
"            background-color: #2b2b2b;\n"
"        }\n"
"QLineEdit:hover{\n"
"    border: 2px solid #FDDE70;\n"
"        }\n"
" QLineEdit:focus{\n"
"      border: 2px solid #FDDE70;\n"
"}")
        self.edit_1.setMaxLength(32767)
        self.edit_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.edit_1.setObjectName("edit_1")

Как это выглядит:

